# error trying to encode sound file to base64

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did this line of code and i got this error " File "C:\Python33\lib\base64.py", line 326, in encode
    output.write(line)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes"

```
import base64

with open('trang_base64.wav', 'rb') as fin, open('output.b64', 'w') as fout:
base64.encode(fin, fout)
```

What's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the output to be in binary mode:

open('output.b64', 'wb')

Python3 assumes text mode unless you specify:

http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: You are totally welcome. Be sure to mark it as the correct answer if you're happy with it!